# Content of a Docker Image that is pushed to DockerHub

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub

I created a Docker image locally using following sample Docker file

```
FROM ubuntu
ADD myfile.zip /opt/myfile.zip
```

If I push the built image to DockerHub as a public image, does that image
contain both files from ubuntu image and myfile.zip or does it only contain myfile.zip? If it contains only myfile.zip, when someone pull the image from DockerHub does he have to manually / automatically pull ubuntu image first?

Answer (score 0):

The image will contain the Ubuntu docker image, and your mufile.zip.

You can check the size shown by

`docker images ubuntu`

and

`docker images yourimage`

Things may have changed since this article

https://www.brianchristner.io/docker-image-base-os-size-comparison/

but Ubuntu was 188 MB at that time, your image should be bigger by the size of your zip

This docker documentation explains it

https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/